# Using vba to select a folder in which to scan specific sheets for data

Tags: excel, vba

So I'm trying to create a macro which will open a file explorer. This will then allow me to select specific workbooks from which to scan the data from.
Here is my current code, which results in a error 424, object required:

```
Sub getDataFromWbs()

 Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'This is where you put YOUR folder name
Dim sFolder As String
' Open the select folder prompt
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    If .Show = -1 Then ' if OK is pressed
        sFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
    End If
End With

If sFolder <> "" Then ' if a file was chosen

'Next available Row on Master Workbook
y = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

'Loop through each file in that folder 
'THE LINE UNDER THIS GETS THE ERROR
For Each wbFile In fldr.Files    

    'Make sure looping only through files ending in .xlsx (Excel files)
    If fso.GetExtensionName(wbFile.Name) = "xlsx" Then

      'Open current book
      Set wb = Workbooks.Open(wbFile.Path)

      'Loop through each sheet (ws)
      For Each ws In wb.Sheets

        'check WS name
        If UCase(ws.Name) = "DATA" Then

      'Last row in that sheet (ws)
          wsLR = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

          'Loop through each record (row 2 through last row)
          For x = 2 To wsLR
            'Put column 1,2,3 and 4 of current sheet (ws) into row y of master sheet, then increase row y to next row
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(y, 1) = ws.Cells(x, 1) 'col 1
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(y, 2) = ws.Cells(x, 2) 'col 1
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(y, 3) = ws.Cells(x, 3) 'col 1
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(y, 4) = ws.Cells(x, 4) 'col 1
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(y, 5) = ws.Cells(x, 5) 'col 1
            y = y + 1
          Next x

        End If
        Next ws

      'Close current book
      wb.Close
    End If

Next wbFile
End If
End Sub
```

Please Note that when I run the code, it opens the file explorer, however no excel workbooks are visible, just the folders

Comment: Usually an error is associated with a line of code.  Why not share that with us?

Comment: Sorry I thought I had. its with "For Each wbFile In fldr.Files"

Comment: Sometimes when a comment is buried in the code indicating the error line, I miss it.

Comment: What is `fldr`?  You never set it to anything, so it is empty. Hence, your error

Comment: I suggest using early binding instead of late binding, especially when you are trying to debug things.  It provides intellisense which can be quite a time saver.  In addition, It is good practice to always declare your variables. In the VBA GUI, you can enforce this by `Tools/Options/Editor/Code Settings` and selecting `Require Variable Declaration`. This will place `OPTION EXPLICIT` at the top of each inserted module (and you can also manually add this to modules created before you selected this option). This will be extremely useful in catching typos, variables of the incorrect type, etc.

Comment: Perhaps I was not clear. You need to set `fldr` to something (eg the folder selected)). When you get to the line that causes the error, `fldr` is **empty**, so `fldr.files` is meaningless.

Comment: Oh i get you now, thanks for all the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare the followings

```
Dim Fso As FileSystemObject, fldr As Folder
```

then after  `If sfolder <> "" Then`  add

```
  Set fldr = Fso.GetFolder(sfolder)
```

Also it is better to use `.value` where data is being fetched to `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1")`

Comment: Where do i declare     Dim Fso As FileSystemObject, fldr as Folder ? I tried declaring it at the start and directly before the code being fixed and both resulted in user-defined type not defined

Comment: It is to be declared at the starting of procedure. Near `Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet` Also advice to add reference of 'Microsoft Scripting  Runtime' (in. Tools-> references)